# How to return two variables from ClientRequest?

Tags: http, asynchronous, request, electron, response

I made http request (Class: ClientRequest) and I need to return two variables from my "login method" via promise.

```
function login(name, pass,server) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const request = net.request({
      method: 'GET',
      url: server+'/names.nsf?Login&Username=' + name + '&Password=' + pass,
      useSessionCookies: true,
      redirect: 'follow'
    }
    )
   
   var first
   var second
    ///first
    request.on('response', (response) => {
      ... 
      first = response.statusCode
    })
   ///second
   request.on('redirect', (statusCode, method, redirectUrl) => {
      ... 
      second = redirectUrl
    })

  resolve([first, second])

    request.end()
    
  });
}
```

And I am using it in this way:

```
ipcMain.on('loginbackend', async (event, arg) => {
 
  try {
    const loginInfo = await login(arg.name, arg.pass,arg.server)
    event.returnValue = loginInfo
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error('ERROR:');
    console.error(error);
  } 
});
```

I can return var putting resolve() into request.on method, but I need return both vars from both request.on. It seems request.on is asynchronize, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should return your variables when `end` event of `response` is emited

```
function login(name, pass, server) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const request = net.request({
                method: 'GET',
                url: server + '/names.nsf?Login&Username=' + name + '&Password=' + pass,
                useSessionCookies: true,
                redirect: 'follow'
            }
        )

        var first
        var second
        ///first
        request.on('response', (response) => {
        ...
            first = response.statusCode


            response.on('end', () => {
                resolve([first, second]);
            });

        })
        ///second
        request.on('redirect', (statusCode, method, redirectUrl) => {
        ...
            second = redirectUrl
        })

        request.end()

    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and doesnt work - it seems it return nothing.

Comment: Yes I have removed old one.

Comment: Ok try to `resolve` when `request`'s  `clsoe` event fired
[The close event indicates that no more events will be emitted on either the request or response objects.](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/client-request#event-error)

Comment: close neither finish events dont work (return undefined).